# How to trigger click on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-binding

I know we can bind event to dynamically created elements like below

```
$('some').on('click','class/id of dynamic ele',function(){});
```

but how to trigger click event on dynamically created element like i have created new element in dom

```
<div class="one">M</div>
```

now how can i `$( ".one" ).trigger( "click" );` ?

Comment: silly. on insertion  call function(){}

Comment: `click` event not appear attached to `.one` at `js` at Question ?

Comment: i just want to perform one click on that div automatically ... not doing something while creating that div which i know how to do

Comment: can you FIDDLE the issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but how to trigger click event on dynamically created element like i
>   have created new element in dom

Try defining `<div class="one">M</div>` without attributes `<div">M</div>`; setting `attributes` at second argument to [`jQuery( html, attributes )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)  , utilizing `.click()`

> `jQuery( html, attributes )`
>
> **html**
>
> Type: htmlString A string defining a
>   single, standalone, HTML element (e.g.  or ).
>
> **attributes**
>
> Type: PlainObject An object of attributes, events, and
>   methods to call on the newly-created element.

---

> **Important**: If the second argument is passed, ***the HTML string in the first argument must represent a simple element with no attributes.***
>   **As of jQuery 1.4**, ***any event type can be passed in***, and the following jQuery methods can be called: val, css, html, text, data,
>   width, height, or offset.

```js
// create dynamic element
$( "<div></div>", {
  "class": "one",
  "text": "abc",
  "on": {
    // attach `click` event to dynamically created element
    "click": function( event ) {
      // Do something
      console.log(event.target, this.textContent)
    }
  }
}).appendTo( "body" )
// trigger `click` event on dynamically created element
.click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).on('click', '.one', function() {
```

use this one to put click on dynamically created element

find the [DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info

Answer (score 3):

Yup. **[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** should do:

***Snippet:***

```js
var myDIV = $('<div id="myDIV">&nbsp;</div>');
$(document.body).append(myDIV);
$(document).on('click', '#myDIV', onClick);
function onClick() {
  alert('hello');
}
myDIV.trigger('click');
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #cc0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But then again, if this is something you want to do when the `document` is ready or when the `window` has loaded, then you probably don't need to `.trigger()`, you can call the function directly.

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever try with **delegate**? if not you try like this for your dynamically added content.

```
$('body').delegate("div.one", "click", function(e){
   // do you other works here
});
```

check this  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sharif084/aw9382va/2/)

Hope your problem is solved. :)

Comment: This is the correct answer to be able to use event handlers on dynamically added content.

Answer (score 2):

Store that element in a variable, use the same to append dynamically in the body and then trigger click on it:

```
var div = "<div class='one'>M</div>";
$("body").append($(div));
//Your code//
$(div).trigger("click");
```

Or if there are multiple elements with same class and this is the last element then:

```
$(".one:last").trigger("click");
```

Comment: i just want to perform one click on that div automatically ... not doing something while creating that div which i know how to do

Answer (score 1):

i am posting this answer as in all the answers i can't see where to put this trigger method.

If you have any implementations like `.append(), .html()` of jquery or `.innerHTML, .appendChild()` of plain js then after execution of it, or i would say whenever you append your element in the DOM, right after it you can use any event to be triggered **but some event has to be bound on it**.

So, element has to be in the DOM to fire/trigger any event.

Take this example:

```js
var div = $('<div id="aaa">aaa</div>');
$(document.body).append(div).on('click', '#aaa', divClik);

function divClik(e) {
  alert(this.id+' clicked.');
}
div.trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you but why cant use somthing like  $('#aaa').click(function(e){  alert(this.id+' clicked.');}); ???

Answer (score 1):

As no FIDDLE provided, I have assumed the following markup

```
<a class="some">Click To Add</a>
<br/>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

css class

```
.one
{
    background-color: Grey;
}
.some
{
     background-color: Red;
}
```

Assigning click event after the control added to the DIV(with container class)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.some').click(function(){
        $('.container').append("<div class='one'>M</div><br/>");
        $('.container div').off('click').on('click',function(){
                alert("Clicked");
        });
    });
});
```

Try The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bqzo62hn/), and share your inputs if any.

Hope this helps ............